# Why does none of NIntegrate tricks work for this code?

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to obtain result of an integral as follows:

```
(* Input of system *)
\[Omega] = 0.01;
m = mp = 1836.;
M = 1. + m;
me = 1;
\[Mu] = (me*mp)/(me + mp);
\[Gamma] = 0.5*M*\[Omega];

(* Input of NDE *)
rMin = 10^-16;
rMax = 50.;
n = 20;
meshDisc = 0.001;
AE2 = 1.1323224166594805`;

V[r_] := -(1/r) + 1/2*\[Mu]*\[Omega]^2*r^2;
eqn = -(1/(2 \[Mu])) Laplacian[f[r], {r}] + V[r] *f[r];

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eqn, DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0., r <= rMin], 
    DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0., r >= rMax]}, f[r], {r, rMin, rMax},
    n, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> meshDisc}}}}] ;
ns = Position[vals, Min[vals]][[1, 1]];
Er = vals[[ns]];
fr = funs[[ns]];
funR[x_] := funR[x] = fr /. r -> x;


RhoMinus2[
   re_] := ((2 \[Pi]*AE2)/(4 \[Gamma])) (M^2/(
    m^2 + m)) (Exp[-2 \[Gamma]*re^2]/re) NIntegrate[
    funR[r]^2/r*
     Exp[-((2 \[Gamma]*m^2)/M^2) r^2] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma]*m)/M) re*r] - 
       Exp[-((4 \[Gamma]*m)/M) re*r]), {r, rMin, rMax}];

VextE[r_] := VextE[r] = (1/2) me*\[Omega]^2*r^2;
4*\[Pi]*NIntegrate[re^2*VextE[re]*RhoMinus2[re], {re, 0, 10}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision, AccuracyGoal -> 30]
```

but it returns zero, while I know the correct answer is around `0.00015`. (note that I use a  numerical function called `funR` in the next calculations) I tried the tricks that had been suggested for the similar questions in MSE (such as limiting the range of integration, increasing `WorkingPrecision` and `AccuracyGoal`, `MaxRecursion` and `MinRecursion`), however they don't work and the result is the same. In addition if we plot the integrand for the specified range, we can obviously see that the area under the curve is not zero:

```
Plot[{re^2*VextE[re]*RhoMinus2[re]}, {re, rMin, 10}, PlotPoints -> 10,
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I have no idea to solve the problem anymore, any idea?

**ADDENDUM**

There is another type of integral which can't be solved by adding `?NumericQ` to the argument:

```
Vk1E[r_?NumericQ] := (D[D[RhoMinus2[r2], r2], 
       r2] + (2/r2) D[RhoMinus2[r2], r2])/RhoMinus2[r2] /. r2 -> r;
Vk2E[r_?NumericQ] := (D[RhoMinus2[r2], r2]/RhoMinus2[r2])^2 /. r2 -> r;
VkinE[r_?NumericQ] := -(1/(2*me)) ((1/2) Vk1E[r] - (1/4) Vk2E[r]);
4*\[Pi]*NIntegrate[re^2*VkinE[re]*RhoMinus2[re], {re, 0, 10}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

in this case I know the correct answer is around `0.4659` and the following photo shows the integrand plot:

[image]

Comment: If you `Clear[RhoMinus2]`, or restart Mathematica, and then change the definition to `RhoMinus2[re_?NumericQ]:=...` then it works. There are examples in the [documentation for NIntegrate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) under "Possible Issues".

Comment: @user293787 Thank you so much, what a subtle point! it worked. However it doesn't work for another type of integral that I should to solve. I have added it to the question as addendum. I'll be so grateful if you can help me to solve it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your ADDENDUM is as follows. First, we should use the @user293787 proposal.

```
RhoMinus2[re_?NumericQ] := ((2 \[Pi]*AE2)/(4 \[Gamma])) (M^2/(m^2 + 
   m)) (Exp[-2 \[Gamma]*re^2]/re) NIntegrate[
funR[r]^2/r*
 Exp[-((2 \[Gamma]*m^2)/M^2) r^2] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma]*m)/M) re*r] - 
   Exp[-((4 \[Gamma]*m)/M) re*r]), {r, rMin, rMax}];
```

Second,  `NDEigensystem` produces an `Interpolation` and its differentiation is slow. It is useful to replace `D[D[RhoMinus2[r2], r2],   r2]` by `D[RhoMinus2[r2], {r2,2}]`. Third, in order to speed up the execution, we decrease `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` (This is described in the documentation.).

```
Vk1E[r_?NumericQ]:=(D[RhoMinus2[r2],{r2, 2}]+(2/r2)*D[RhoMinus2[r2],r2])/RhoMinus2[r2]/.r2->r;
Vk2E[r_?NumericQ] := (D[RhoMinus2[r2], r2]/RhoMinus2[r2])^2 /. r2 -> r;
VkinE[r_?NumericQ] := -(1/(2*me)) ((1/2) Vk1E[r] - (1/4) Vk2E[r]);
4*\[Pi]*NIntegrate[Evaluate[re^2*VkinE[re]*RhoMinus2[re]], {re, 0, 10}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4] // Timing
```

> `{506.5, 0.4677828900}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please specify the `AccuracyGaol` in your code. One more question: Think about a multidimensional `NIntegrate` instead of derivations, what points you suggest to get the correct result?

Comment: @Wisdom: Sorry for the typo. Fixed. Concerning multidimensional integrals, I think  `Method->MonteCarlo` would be the right choice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.